# Combining two TileWMS with different axisOrientation using OpenLayers3?

Tags: wms, openlayers

I have two TileWMS, one that has map data, with terrain, roads and stuff. And one that only is images that should be placed upon the map. Both uses the same projection, ESPG:3006.

The one hosting the map is a WMS of version 1.1.1 and the other 1.3.

Is it possible to set these to to work?

I have managed to setup a map where both have the same `axisOrientation`, specifically `"neu"` but I have not managed to get it to run with different axisOrientations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should miss the point. You just need to set the WMS version for each WMS and the orientation will solve by itself.

See [this discussion on the developer Mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/p8RnRNgdzi4) and the [documentation for WMS](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html) in particular the `params` section.